# Verificar campo Disabled no katalon

Tags: testes, testes-funcionais, testes-automatizados

Preciso verificar oque esta retornando dentro de um campo disabled, utilizando a ferramenta katalon para fazer o teste automatizado. Exemplo: quero verificar oque esta dentro dos campos da imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]